# PHP MySQL Multiple Checkbox Update Record

Tags: php, mysql

In need of help, 
I'm trying to multiple update using checkbox.

Here is my Query

PHPUpdateCheckBox.php

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("database");

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["chkSub"]);$i++)
    {
        if($_POST["chkSub"][$i] != "")
        {
            $strSQL = "UPDATE example_db
                       SET submitted = 'Y'  
                       WHERE exp_hdr_no = '".$_POST["chkSub"][$i]."' ";
            $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        }
    }

    echo "Record Updated.";

mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Here is my website

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HEADER</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function ClickCheckAll(vol)
    {

        var i=1;
        for(i=1;i<=document.frmMain.hdnCount.value;i++)
        {
            if(vol.checked == true)
            {
                eval("document.frmMain.chkSub"+i+".checked=true");
            }
            else
            {
                eval("document.frmMain.chkSub"+i+".checked=false");
            }
        }
    }

    function onUpdate()
    {
        if(confirm('Do you want to Submit?')==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="frmMain" action="PHPUpdateCheckBox.php" method="post" OnSubmit="return onUpdate();">
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("database");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM expample_db";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=exp_hdr_no&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Header No </div></th>
    <th width="98"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=cust_name&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Customer Name </div></th>
    <th width="97"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=time_in&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Time In</div></th>
    <th width="59"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=time_out&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Time Out </div></th>
    <th width="71"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=ref_type_code&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Ref Type Code </div></th>
    <th width="59"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?sort=ref_no&order=<?php echo $strNewOrder?>"> <div align="center">Ref No </div></th>
    <th>
        Submitted
      <input name="CheckAll" type="checkbox" id="CheckAll" value="Y" onClick="ClickCheckAll(this);">
    </div></th>
  </tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
$i++;
?>
  <tr>
   <td><div align="center"><div align="center"><?php echo $objResult["exp_hdr_no"];?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $objResult["cust_name"];?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $objResult["time_in"];?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $objResult["time_out"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $objResult["ref_type_desc"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $objResult["ref_no"];?></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chkSub[]" id="chkSub<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $objResult["submitted"];?>"></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnCount" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of Site
[image]

I'm trying to update the 'Submitted' Column only, if someone can help me, thanks!

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not put the key in WHERE condition

change

```
WHERE '".$_POST["chkSub"][$i]."'
```

to

```
WHERE `col_name` = '".$_POST["chkSub"][$i]."'
```

Comment: Oh did I. hahaha. Sorry! I tried it already. Still doesn't update when I tick the checkbox